# Question regarding shifting of origin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

At what point the origin be shifted, if the coordinates of a point $(-1,8)$ becomes $(-7,3)$.

Let origin be shifted by $(h,k)$. so we have

$-1=-7+h$

$8=3+k$

solving i get $(h,k)=(6,5)$. But textbook states answer to be $(-6,-5)$. i am thoroughly confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it backwards, so you get the opposite answer. $(-1,8)$ *becomes* $(-7,3)$ so you are shifting $(-1,8) \to (-7,3).$ So $$ -1+h = -7 \\ 8+k = 3.$$

Comment: formula is $x=X+h$ ,

Comment: @Gathdi If $-1$ becomes $-7$ what does $0$ become?

Comment: okay got it thanks

Answer (score 2):

All points get the same shift, so:

if $(−1,8)+(h,k)=(−7,3)$,

then the shift is $(h,k)=(−7,3)-(−1,8)=(−6,−5)$

Because the shift is the same for all points, then is the same for the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y) = (-1,8)$ be the original point, and $(x',y') = (-7,3)$ the shifted point.

Shift:

$P(x,y)$ $ \rightarrow $ $P'(x',y')$, where

$1) x $$ \rightarrow$ $x' = x + a$;

$2) y $$ \rightarrow$ $ y' = y + b$.

As row vectors:

$(x',y') =  (x,y) + (a,b)$.

Now calculate $a$ and $b$:

$1) - 7 = - 1 + a$,

$ a = - 6$;

$2) 3   = 8 + b$,

$b= - 5$.

Shift of origin $O$ $\rightarrow$ $O'$ :

$(x',y') = (0,0) + (-6,-5) = (-6,-5)$.